# Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
<form class="modal-content" id="bookingForm">
    <div class="formContainer">
      <h1>Booking Form</h1>
      <p>Please fill in this form to Book The Trip.</p>
      <hr>
      <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required id="email">


      <label><b>Package</b></label>

      <input type="text" id="packageFields" name="teste2">

      <label for="psw"><b>Name</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" required id="name">

      <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Phone No.</b></label>
      <input type="tel" placeholder="Enter Phone No." name="psw-repeat" required id="phone">

      <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Date Of Journey</b></label>
      <input type="date" placeholder="Enter Phone No." name="psw-repeat" required id="date">

      <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

      <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="submit" class="signupbtn">Confirm Booking</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('bookingForm').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
    </section>
    <!-- animation -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script>
    AOS.init();

    var modal = document.getElementById('bookingForm');
// Script To Copy Package Name To The Form Automatically
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function setPackage(packageName) {
  document.querySelector('#packageFields').value = packageName;
}
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.5/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <!-- Insert these scripts at the bottom of the HTML, but before you use any Firebase services -->

 <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
 <script src="/__/firebase/7.14.5/firebase-app.js"></script>

 <!-- If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Analytics -->
 <script src="/__/firebase/7.14.5/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

 <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
 <script src="/__/firebase/7.14.5/firebase-auth.js"></script>
 <script src="/__/firebase/7.14.5/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
 <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
 <script src="bookingSubmit.js">    </script>
```

This Is The Html And The JavaSript Is Given Below:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: "AIzaSyDT80mEpNS4CpdByl2ugrSTGzgQpkbzzeI",
   authDomain: "himwhitecab.firebaseapp.com",
   databaseURL: "https://himwhitecab.firebaseio.com",
   projectId: "himwhitecab",
   storageBucket: "himwhitecab.appspot.com",
   messagingSenderId: "505950138314",
   appId: "1:505950138314:web:c37c1b2c593f30e911e933",
   measurementId: "G-ECR97G3YY0"
 };

//reference messages collection


firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var firestore =  firebase.firestore();

const submitBtn = document.querySelector("#signupbtn");


let email = document.querySelector('#email');
let packageFields = document.querySelector('#packageFields');
let name = document.querySelector('#name');
let phone = document.querySelector('#phone');
let date = document.querySelector('#date');

const db = firestore.collection(BookingData);

submitBtn.addEventListner('click', function(){
  let userEmailInput = email.value;
  let userPackageInput = packageFields.value;
  let userNameInput = name.value;
  let userPhoneInput = phone.value;
  let userDateInput = date.value;

  db.doc()
  .set({
    email:userEmailInput,
    package:userPackageInput,
    name:userNameInput,
    phone:userPhoneInput,
    date:userDateInput
  })
  .then(function(){
    console.log("Data Saved");
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
  });
});
```

I am using this to store the data of my contact forms in my Firebase.

But It Gives The Error:

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).
>       at initializeApp ([http://localhost:5000/**/firebase/7.14.5/firebase-app.js:1:15287**](http://localhost:5000/__/firebase/7.14.5/firebase-app.js:1:15287))
>       at Object.ee.initializeApp ([http://localhost:5000//firebase/7.14.5/firebase-app.js:1:19566](http://localhost:5000/__/firebase/7.14.5/firebase-app.js:1:19566))
>       at http://localhost:5000/bookingSubmit.js:15:10

How To Solve This Problem....??

Thanks For Help In Advance.

PS: I am Also using one more html file called index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get that error message if you try to execute `initializeApp()` more than once on the same page.

Your first execution is here:

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Your second execution is actually inside this script include:

```
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

If you want to use that script to automatically initialize Firebase, then you don't need to call initializeApp manually.  Just make sure your Firebase code runs **after** that script executes.

Comment: Yeah It Solved The Error I mentioned Earlier but it Gave a new error **Uncaught ReferenceError: BookingData is not defined
    at bookingSubmit.js:27**           _BookingData_ is the name of my collection in Firebase.